# Taking the limit of $r \to 0$ in $f(t) \leq Cg(r)$ when this inequality holds for all $ r > 0$

Tags: analysis, inequality, continuity

Good morning

I have proved the following inequalty:

$$f(t) \leq Cg(r) \quad \text{for all $t\in [0,T]$ and $r > 0$}$$
for two functions $f$ and $g$, both of which are continuous.

Am I allowed to take the limit as $r \to 0$ in this inequality, given that I know $g(r) \to g_0$ as $r \to 0$, and conclude that
$$f(t) \leq Cg_0 \quad \text{for all $t \in [0,T]$}?$$
I think it is true, though I feel a bit strange since when I derived the first inequality, I strongly used the fact that $r$ is strictly non-zero and positive.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is some $t_0 \in [0, T]$, s.t. $f(t_0) > C g_0$. Denote $f_0 = f(t_0)$ Consider the function $g^*(x)$, defined as follows:
$$
    g^*(x) = \begin{cases}
    C g_0 - f_0 & \text{$x \leq 0$}\\
    C g(x) - f_0 & \text{$x > 0$}
    \end{cases}
$$
As $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous and $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = g_0$, it can be shown, that $g^*(x)$ is continuous, too. By our assymption $g^*(0) = Cg_0 - f_0 < 0$. Then there is a neighbourhood $(-\delta, \delta)$, s.t. $g^*(x) < 0$ when $x\in (-\delta, \delta)$. Particularly $0 > g^*(\delta / 2) = C g(\delta/2) - f_0 = C g(\delta / 2) - f(t_0)$, i.e. $C g(\delta/2) < f(t_0)$. Contradiction.